How can I use \input with relative figure folders?
I am trying to make a main file with \input of a bunch of tex files. These tex files use \Figures... . png as images in each folder of each tex file. The \input in the main tex file gives the error figures/1.png not found: using draft setting.
How can I get the images in the folder of the \input tex file?
This is the code of producing the error(s)
\begin{center}
  \resizebox{0.5\linewidth}{!}{
    \includegraphics{Figures/1.png}
  }
\end{center}

Another tex file then attempts to input this with the following:
\input{../Example/Example.tex

Inside of the Example folder there is the Figures folder an the Example.tex, which has the code I put above.
When I run the \input file it gives multiple errors (one for each image):

Package pdftex.def: File `Figures/1.png' not found: using draft setting.

The image is in the folder, and when I run the example.tex file by itself (with preamble etc.) it displays the image fine. The error only occurs when trying to \input the file.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

you need to use / not \  for path separator and you need to use the right directory name, (you show Figures and figures in different parts of your question) you do not show your input or the error but your description suggests you are using \Figures with a \  which most likely would give an undefined csname error for the command \Figures. Paths are always relative to the working directory of the tex process, not relative to the file

@DavidCarlisle In each individua; tex file it works fine but it doesn't work when I use \include

you are giving no clues about your error message or the input. you can not \include a document that works as an individual file. Also your statements are inconsistent, your question says you use \input but your last comment says \include, and as previously noted you say you use \Figures (which won't work) but show a fragment of an error message that suggests you used /figures. Please edit the question so it has enough information that it can be answered.

@DavidCarlisle Sorry I meant \input. I am trying to \input a tex file with a \includegraphics in i, it works in the normal file but when I try to input it (without the begin document preamble etc.) it says it can't find t he image folder. Inside the tex file it is include graphs (\Figures\1.png etc.) How do I refrence this folder in the input

you should fix your question rather than provide multiple inconsistent comments, but when you \input the section it is as if you cut and paste that text into the main document and any references to graphics files must use the same paths as they would be if they were in the main file.

Is there any code I can put in my main file which can mean it fixes this, because I have a separate image folder (Figures) for every tex file

how can we know what "this" is that needs fixing if you do not say what you did or what error message you got other than vague, inconsistent hints?

I told the error message figures/1.png not found: using draft setting. This error shows up for every figures folder in every tex file for every image

you get that message if you use \includegraphics{figures/1.png} and there is no such file at that path starting from the directory in which you started latex.   You have repeatedly indicated using \Figures which would not produce that message, and the solution is to put the image at that location or change the argument to have a correct path to the figure, but you have given no indication about what that should be.

I meant Figures I forgot to capitalise the f. I have 2 tex files. One is a main file with \input of the other tex file. This other one has a \include Figures ... When this one is run standalone it works. When it is run with the \input I get that error. So the issue is that, when running the main file, the images are not recognised, and idk why this is. The image exists in the Figures folder. The figures folder and the .tex file (not the main) are in the same folder.

"I forgot to capitalise the f" that, on it's own, would be enough (depending on the operating system) to generate the error message you show. And now you are back to \include  when before you said \input. why can you not edit the question to have any information to allow an answer to be given? I'll vote to close as unclear, if it does get closed it can still be re-opened if you make the question understandable.

No, I forgot to capitalise the f in my response, not the code. It is \input, I tried \include and it gave the same error

@DavidCarlisle The full error is :Package pdftex.def: File `Figures/1.png' not found: using draft setting.
It occurs everytime I use \includegraphs in one of the individual tex files
I \input the tex  file and \inputgraphs the images in \Figures

Yes I know that error message, I wrote it. But all we know is that you have the wrong path but since you have no information in the question and write a different path in every other comment I am not going to guess what the path should be

@DavidCarlisle I have edited the question with all info

You have not exactly shown usable code, but I assume you want \includegraphics{../Example/Figures/1.png}

include - How to make the main file recognize relative paths used in the imported files? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange ?

Thanks David  that fixed it

You need the path relative to the tex process, so
\includegraphics{../Example/Figures/1.png}

If you want to use the same tex fragment in diffewrent contexts you can use a macro for the path so define
\newcommand\figurepath{../Example/Figures}

\includegraphics{\figurepath/1.png}

Then in some other document you might be able to use the same fragment but with
\newcommand\figurepath{./Figures}

or
\newcommand\figurepath{.}

or whatever you need.
